# Hadoop installation on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, hadoop

I installed Hadoop on ubuntu from the .deb package when I run start-all.sh I get this error
I configured the core-site.xml for hdfs:localhost:9001 but i gives me the error. I think the problem in the path of the conf dir in the hadoop-env.sh I set the path to /usr/shar/hadoop/templates/conf and tried /etc/hadoop/conf I copied the dir to this locatiob but I get the error please help me. I need it for my college project and I spent half of the semester trying to fix the problem without succesed.

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getServiceAddress(NameNode.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.(DataNode.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1590)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1751)

---

FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.(JobTracker.java:2070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.(JobTracker.java:1889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.(JobTracker.java:1883)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:298)

### at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4791)

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1419)

---

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getServiceAddress(NameNode.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.(SecondaryNameNode.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:650)

---

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: local
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.(TaskTracker.java:1532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3906)

Answer (score 0):

For starting the NameNode and DataNode, try some changes in core-site.xml under property of fs.default.name:
hdfs://master:9000/tmp (try adding a folder path; tmp in this case)